# How to fix pgr_dijkstra error, query must return columns 'id', 'source', 'target' and 'cost'?

Tags: pgrouting

I followed the steps in "pgRouting 2.0 for Windows quick guide". At the step of running pgr_dijkstra using the sql below:

```
SELECT id, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost, the_geom
  FROM pgr_dijkstra(
    'SELECT gid, source, target, st_length(geom) as cost FROM public.roads_svy21',
    1, 3000, false, false
  ) as di
  JOIN public.roads_svy21_vertices_pgr pt
  ON di.id2 = pt.id ;
```

It returned me an error message below:

Error, query must return columns 'id', 'source', 'target' and 'cost'

What is the possible cause of the error?

Answer (score 4):

The possible cause is what the error says: the first argument of the `pgr_dijkstra(sql:text,..)` function must contain an SQL statement, which returns `id`, `source`, `target` and `cost`.

In your case you query for `gid`, but it should return `id` as column name.

```
SELECT id, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost, the_geom
  FROM pgr_dijkstra(
    'SELECT gid AS id, source, target, st_length(geom) as cost FROM public.roads_svy21',
    1, 3000, false, false
  ) as di
  JOIN public.roads_svy21_vertices_pgr pt
  ON di.id2 = pt.id ;
```